# Correct way to use access level

Tags: javascript, php, session

A part of my web is pay per view, so I have to hide dom elements or show using access level.
I store access level in MySQL. Value 0 is a standard value that user gets after creating account. After the login, he will have some functions on my web but not everything. To unlock rest he will need to buy a plan, and then his access level will increase up to 1.
So regarding that, how to work with that access level. Should I use?

```
$_SESSION['access']= $row['access'];
```

And after that something like:

```
if($_SESSION['access'] == 1){
// user with access lvl 1 can go to locked window
echo '<script> function goLocation(val){
    window.location.href= "http://www.someweb.co.uk/load.php?titleID="+val;
}</script>'}
else{
// user with access lvl 0 can't go to locked window
echo '<script> function goLocation(val){
    alert("Page locked... If you would like to go there buy a access");
}</script>'}
```

Or I should store it as cookie

```
$cookie_name = "access";
$cookie_value = $row['access'];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

And after that call cookie using JavaScript:

```
 getCookie('access');
 function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            accessLVL = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            return accessLVL;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And run main code:

```
function goLocation(val){
if(accessLVL == 1){
            window.location.href= "http://www.someweb.co.uk/load.php?titleID="+val;
        }
else{
alert("Page locked... If you would like to go there buy a access");
}
```

I know I can do it also by AJAX call, but I do now want to wait for callback.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Anything you do client-side is really easy to get around using the browser developer tools...

Comment: Stick with the PHP version, if the user doesn't know what code is used, it's harder to guess what they need to do to get access (besides pay).

Comment: as @fredrik said, the best way to protect your "member areas" is to not render the informations in the webpage. So your php solutions is the best

Comment: ok thanks guys for feedback

Answer (score 0):

If you do the check in Javascript, an attacker (or a bad user) can bypass the check and get what he wants.

So you must check the access in PHP with `session`. Even if you are checking in PHP, do not trust the cookie's values. Because the values in `session` are at server side and can be trusted, while the values in `cookie` can be set from client side and can be set to any one.